# Distribution of the stopping time of an autoregressive sequence

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, random-walks, martingales

Consider $e_t$ being i.i.d. uniformly chosen from $\pm 1$. Let $\eta$ be a small positive constant. What is the distribution of $T$ such that $\eta^{0.5} (1+\eta)^T W_T$ first hits $\pm 1$, in which
$$
W_T = \sum_{t=1}^T \eta^{0.5} (1+\eta)^{-t} e_t.
$$
Note $W_T \approx N(0,1/2)$ when $T$ is large.

Note $x^{(t)}$ is the closed-form representation of the following autoregressive iteration
$$
x^{(t)} = (1+\eta) x^{(t-1)} + \eta e_t,
$$
where $x^{(0)} = 0$. It is straightforward to observe that the iteration $x^{(T)} = \eta^{0.5} (1+\eta)^T W_T$.

Comment: It seems that there is a positive probability that $T$ is infinite: imagine that sufficiently many first $e_t$'s have taken the $-1$ value, so that $x^{(t)}\le -1$. Then, starting from this moment all the $x^{(s)}$ will be $\le -1$.

Should it be "first hits $\pm 1$'' instead?

Comment: @VictorKleptsyn Sorry for the delayed reply. I have modified the question to be $\pm 1$. Thanks for pointing out!